# 'Get-Content' fails from a file in a shared folder?

Tags: powershell

The script below works like a dream on a local drive:

```
 $File = 'c:\scripts\File.reg'
 $Content = Get-Content -Path $File | 
 ForEach-Object {
    $_ -replace 'user',$ENV:USERNAME
 } 
 Set-Content -Path $File -Value $Content
```

How can I get this script to work for a file found on a shared drive ?

Obviously this does not work:

```
 $File = '\\server\sharedfolder\file.reg'
 $Content = Get-Content -Path $File | 
 ForEach-Object {
    $_ -replace 'user',$ENV:USERNAME
} 
 Set-Content -Path $File -Value $Content
```

I'm just right clicking on the ps1 file and running with powershell, I get this error:

> "Get-Content : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is
>   null.  At C:\users\bob\desktop\script.ps1:2 char:30
>   +$Content = Get-Content -Path $file |

Comment: Your code should work fine, PS has no issues with UNC paths and should be able to read a file from a share (assuming you have permissions to access it!) in the same manner it does from a local drive. What error do you get with your code?

Comment: Why "obviously this does not work"?

Comment: There is no **"Obviously"**. You need to tell us what happens when you try it. Are you trying to run this as a service or scheduled task, where the process is likely using a different user account?

Comment: You guys are definitely correct. Allow me to make amends. The error message  that I get  is added to my original question.

Comment: However the `$file` variable is constructed, the result is empty and does not contain the shared folder path you think it does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is in your file...

The code should work as is. If not something else is amiss.

Example:

```
PS C:\Scripts> ($file = '\\fs01\Data\New Text Document.txt')

\\fs01\Data\New Text Document.txt

PS C:\Scripts> Get-Content -Path $File

New text doc 

user
user1
2user

PS C:\Scripts> $Content = $null

PS C:\Scripts> $Content

PS C:\Scripts> $Content = Get-Content -Path $File | 
ForEach-Object {
$_ -replace 'user',$ENV:USERNAME
}

PS C:\Scripts> $Content 
New text doc 

Administrator
Administrator1
2Administrator

PS C:\Scripts> $File

\\fs01\Data\New Text Document.txt

PS C:\Scripts> Set-Content -Path $File -Value $Content

PS C:\Scripts> Get-Content -Path $File

New text doc 

Administrator
Administrator1
2Administrator
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you are handling files with `reg`extension, I suspect you are running your code from `Registry` provider. In that case you have to specify the `Filesystem` provider in your UNC path: (notice double colon)

```
$File = 'Filesystem::\\server\sharedfolder\file.reg'
```